# Qt: crash when changing centralWidget

Tags: c++, qt, class

I created own class, here is `ewindow.h`:

```
#ifndef EWINDOW_H
#define EWINDOW_H
#include <QWidget>
#include <QString>
#include <mainwindow.h>

class MainWindow;

class EWindow
{
    public:
        EWindow(void (*callback)(EWindow*, MainWindow*), MainWindow *window, QString name, QString title);
        QWidget *widget;
        void resize(int width, int height);
        void move(int x, int y);
        void move();
        void apply();
        void append(QWidget *newWidget);
        int* getSize();
        ~EWindow();

    private:
        int width, height, x, y;
        QString name, title;
        MainWindow *window;
};

#endif // EWINDOW_H
```

Constructor:

```
EWindow::EWindow(void (*callback)(EWindow*, MainWindow*), MainWindow *window, QString name, QString title) {
    this->width = 0;
    this->height = 0;
    this->x = -1;
    this->y = -1;
    this->name = name;
    this->title = title;
    this->window = window;
    this->widget = new QWidget();
    (*callback)(this, window);
}
```

In callback i creating some widgets like `QLabel` or `QLineEdit`.
Here is my `apply` function:

```
void EWindow::apply() {
    window->setCentralWidget(this->widget);
    window->setWindowTitle(this->title);
    window->setFixedWidth(this->width);
    window->setFixedHeight(this->height);
    if (this->x == -1 || this->y == -1) this->move();
    window->move(this->x, this->y);
}
```

But! When i trying to call apply function 2 times for different EWindows my program crashes without any errors. I think error in this line: `window->setCentralWidget(this->widget);`. Help please, thanks.

Comment: Use a debugger to pinpoint the exact location of the crash (and, why not, even solve it at the same time :) )

Comment: Thanks for advice, but, unfortunately, i dont know how to use debugger :( I thought it is known problem.

Comment: ***i dont know how to use debugger*** Time to learn. This is one of the most important skills to learn as a programmer.

Comment: ***I thought it is known problem*** Here is a guess. Watch out for double deletes. Remember that Qt automatically deletes child objects when the parent is freed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem more. I forgot that Qt deletes previous `QWidget` when applying new. I did it it this way:

Callback will not be called in constructor, only in function `apply()`, after creating new instance of `QWidget`. Now it works great. Thanks, `drescherjm`!